# Problem spring roo and Maven enviroment variables

Tags: maven-2, environment-variables, spring-roo

I am having this problem in the image:
[image]

even if in the path displayed is correct and exists. I tryed anyway to change this variable and the files in `C:\\Program Files\Java\apache-maven-2.2.1` or `C:\\Program Files\Java\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin` or `C:\\Program Files\apache-maven-2.2.1\bin` as I read in different forums.

My enviroment variables are set up as follow:

```
Path=%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%ROO_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;
M2_HOME=C:\Program Files\apache-maven-2.2.1  
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18
ROO_HOME=C:\spring-roo-1.1.0.RC1
```

Must I do something extra?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what I did was uninstall and reintall, the old 'trick'.
Worked :s

Answer (score 0):

Try without spaces in the path or between quotes.

M2_HOME="C:\Program Files\apache-maven-2.2.1"

Answer (score 0):

I've *not* set up M2_HOME nor ROO_HOME at all (only JAVA_HOME) and everything works for me.

Try without them, they might be automatically deduced at runtime?

YMMV: I'm developing in Linux not Windows.

(Edit: of course, you'll need to fixup your PATH if you do that)

Comment: JAVA_HOME works perfectly, the problem is I need at least M2_HOME to be able to run any mvn command